# Join AVCHD .mts files on linux

Tags: linux, video, h.264, audio-video-sync

I have a Lumix camera which, like most new cameras, record video in AVCHD format. The files get segmented into 2 or 4 GiB segments because of the limitations of the filesystem used on the memory card.

When I transfer the files to my linux computer to edit them I naturally want to have each video in a single file, which is no problem at all for linux's filesystems. So, how can I **losslessly** join these segments, maintaining a/v-sync?

(With Avidemux 2.6.8 I can append these segments, but it leads to nasty distortions at the cut point.)

Comment: I don't understand why my question was downvoted, but I would like to, so that I won't repeat my mistake. Was it because I listed only avidemux instead of all the dozen or so other programs/methods I've tried? (Anyway, after countless other tries I finally found one method which works well enough for my current set of files, so I'll just answer myself then, using the "Answer Your Question"-button, I suppose.)

Comment: I get random down-votes with no comments all the time.  I think its like anonymous vandalism.  People get a kick out of it.  I appreciate you posting your findings.  I can make use of your answer.  I try to do the same - share the knowledge gained from the effort...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution, which seems to work with my files at least, turned out to be very simple:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:00000.MTS|00001.MTS|00002.MTS" -c copy output.mts
```

One still has to figure out which of the files belong together, though.

Comment: "-c copy" if you don't want hours of transcoding